# Why is acetone and diethyl ether miscible, but not water and diethyl ether?

Tags: solubility, polarity

Acetone and Water are miscible, and water and diethyl ether are not. So why are acetone and diethyl ether miscible if water and acetone seem to have similar polarities?

Answer (score 5):

Acetone's dipole moment is 2.91D while that of ether is only 1.15D.  Water is a very polar substance, so acetone will dissolve in it while ether will not.

Two substances are miscible when their intermolecular forces (IMFs) are similar enough such that the forces of attraction between molecules of different substances are similar in strength to the forces of attraction between molecules of the same substance.  If we look at the miscibility of A and B as an example, if A attracts B about as strongly as A attracts A and B attracts B the substances should be miscible.  If A and A have much stronger attraction than A and B the substances are less likely to be miscible.

In your example it's not that some molecules of ether will not dissolves in water and vice versa, it's just that if the two liquids are in contact the water will stay with water and the ether with ether for the most part.  This is because water's strongest IMF is hydrogen bonding while ether's is dispersion with some dipole-dipole forces.